# Fetching value in excel table from another excel table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a main excel file(MAIN.xlsm) that has a list of tasks assigned to different people.

This file contains a rootFolder Name defined to a cell that has the location of this main file.

The major content of this file is a table that contains the following in rows:
Task no (1,2,3 so on)
Customer(Customer Name)
Project (Project belonging to the customer above)
Task Name(Task in this specific Project) this value is hyperlinked to another excel file(details below*)
Last Status

In the folder which contains this Main file I have folders of all the customers, these customer
folders have subfolders with their respective projects.
*Inside these subfolders I have excel files(of all tasks in the respective project, say Task1) which is hyperlinked to each task listed in the main file.

The hyperlink is working fine.

Now in each Task file(Task1) I have a sheet 'INFO' with a table which lists out all the activities in the task that are being carried out. My associates are supposed to be filling these files. Now I have a name lastStatus defined to the last cell of this table, It could be something like 'under process', 'stage 1 complete', etc.

My issue is I am trying to fetch this lastStatus of each excel file into the Main file. I am using formula something like this in the Last Status Column

```
=INDIRECT("'"&rootFolder&"\"&Table[[#This Row],[Customer]]&"\"&Table[[#This Row],[Project]]&"\["&Table[[#This Row],[Task Name]]&".xlsx]INFO'!lastStatus
```

It throws #REF!

Without INDIRECT the result looks something like this:
'\server-1\tasks_assigned\My_tasks\CUST1\Light Project[Task1.xlsx]INFO'!lastStatus

Funny thing is, when I paste the result of this formula without INDIRECT outside of the table with an '=' in front, it comes just fine.

Also I noted that when I do so, links get activated in the data ribbon.

I hope I have described the problem in the best way possible. How do I solve this issue ?

Thanks!

Comment: INDIRECT only works on open workbooks. Better to use VBA.

Comment: Any reference to achieve it ?

Comment: Basically I need the definition of a function that can take the destination file location as an argument, and return the value of 'lastStatus' from this destination file.